# Regular expression, re.compile, returning None instead of matching

Tags: python, xml, regex

I am trying to compile a regular expression in Python. 
The below field is in pdml (which is a XML based) format.

```
showname: Origin-Host:0005-diamproxy.WSBOMAGJPNC.Gx.vzims.com
```

My regex is:

```
re.compile (showname="Origin-Host: ([^"]+))")
```

It is giving me `None` at the output when I try to search through the pattern. I think there is something wrong with my regex.

What is wrong with the regex and how should I fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you think your `re.compile` line is supposed to do. That method doesn't even take an argument called `showname`, that line is going to give you an error before you even get to anything else.

Comment: I meant re.compile ("Origin-Host: ([^"]+))")

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
r = re.compile('showname: Origin-Host:(.+)')
```

It'll work with the sample input:

```
s = 'showname: Origin-Host:0005-diamproxy.WSBOMAGJPNC.Gx.vzims.com'
r.match(s).group(0) 
=> 'showname: Origin-Host:0005-diamproxy.WSBOMAGJPNC.Gx.vzims.com'
r.match(s).group(1)
=> '0005-diamproxy.WSBOMAGJPNC.Gx.vzims.com'
```

The code in the question has problems with the quotes, notice that `compile()` receives a string as a parameter.